# Много button один TextView

Tags: button, android, textview

Здравствуйте. В общем, есть несколько кнопок. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию выводилась некая инфа в textview. Для первой кнопки я использую следующий код:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); 
    button.setOnClickListener(listener); 
} 
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener()        
      @Override  
      public void onClick(View v) { 
         textView.setText(R.string.sud);  
      } 
    }; 
}
```

Подскажите, как добавить последующие кнопки?

Comment: @Denbka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Ну и для остальных кнопок используйте то же самое. Присвойте им ваш листенер и в нем смотрите, что нажато:

```
 @Override  
 public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

        case (R.id.button1):
            textView.setText("Button1");

        case (R.id.button2):
            textView.setText("Button2");

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OnClick есть у кнопок, ставь в XML и все onClick

Comment: НИКОГДА не ставьте onClick в XML.